# google map fusion table - simple query to select country polygon is not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have created a new fusion table. I want to fire a query to retrieve a particular country polygon with a particular color. But it's not working. I am sure I am doing something wrong in where clause.
Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>  
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Fusion Tables Layer Example: Basic Fusion Tables Layer</title>
<link href="http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/samples/style/default.css"   rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">       </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4, -122.1),
zoom: 2,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
select: 'geometry',
from: '1hFPiPmQilakQ4zESVCJqq9ENmeo5e_EJXy_Usy8',
where : countryName = 'India'
},
map: map
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the where clause.  Also, the columns are case sensitive (your table doesn't have a "countryName" column, it's "CountryName"

Therefore, just switch in this line:

```
 where : "CountryName = 'India'"
```